# How to remove wireless LAN "whitelist" on Compaq QC-60-419wm?

Tags: wireless, bios

My wireless LAN card is disabled in the BIOS. I have the original Phoenix BIOS file as well as the modified BIOS that is supposed to remove the wireless LAN "whitelist". It appears that I need Windows to update the BIOS. However, I do not have Windows on this computer.

How can I do this with Ubuntu?

Both the original and modified BIOS files can be found [here](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/printthread.php?t=20223&pp=40&page=18).

Comment: I have read, but not tried, that if you create a Windows 7 rescue disk, you can boot from that disk into a cmd terminal, and execute the bios setup programs from there.

Comment: i tried that, didnt work, what i had to do in the long run is get my install disk for my desktop and install a temporary windows. now i have windows off, its reading(sort of) but now i have driver issues. I have the drivers from broadcom but i dont know how to install them.

Comment: Are you sure you have the broadcom card?  Apparently some of the QC60 shipped with an Atheros card.  A couple of things to try:

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the broadcom card?  Apparently some of the QC60 shipped with an Atheros card.  A couple of things to try: `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree` might help with some of the hardware issues. you should reboot after doing that install.

Type into a terminal window `sudo lshw -C network`  If you see the broadcom BCM4311 network card listed, try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer 
sudo reboot
```